# Database for scheduling - use cron to schedule individual tasks based on repeating schedule?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm currently designing a database that:

1) Has a list of Tasks, such as:

```
Clean the floor.
Wipe the sink.
Take swabs.
```

2) Has a list of Areas, such as:

```
Kitchen.
Servery.
```

3) Tasks are scheduled against an area, either as "Hourly", "Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly" or "Annually".  I'll call this AreaTask (Area, Task, Frequency) :-

```
Kitchen, Clean the floor, Daily
```

4) An AreaTask will become due either at the start of a working day (if it is Daily, Weekly, Monthly or Annually), or at the start of the hour if it is Hourly - based on the schedule.  For example, if "Clean the floor" is scheduled "Weekly" on Wednesdays, then at the start of each Wednesday it will become Due, and remain Due for the day until it has been done (Worked, Signed off, etc) - or it will become OverDue if it goes beyond a certain time.

5) When work is done against an AreaTask, it is logged in the database (Area, Task, User [whom did the work], DateTime [that the work was done]) : -

```
Kitchen, Clean the floor, Joe Bloggs, 2012-05-23 10:50:00
```

Here is what I'm trying to decide:

I can *determine* the various states of a AreaTask at any particular time by queries alone because all of the data is there (i.e. I can determine that an AreaTask will of become Due on Wednesday, and I can determine that it became overdue if no Work was done against that AreaTask before a set time).  However, I'm wondering if instead I should have a AreaTaskDue table that is populated perhaps by a CRON job, or some other means.

This way I have a formal entry in the database to query and store data against, for example:

ScheduledTask (Area, Task, ScheduledDateTime)
    Kitchen, Clean the floor, 2012-05-23 06:00:00

This would also allow a task to be scheduled manually should the need arise.

Then when work is done against a ScheduledTask, it can be logged against the ScheduledTask itself:

ScheduledTaskWork (Area,Task,ScheduledDateTime,User,DateTime)
    Kitchen, Clean the floor, 2012-05-23 06:00:00, Joe Bloggs, 2012-05-23 11:30:00

I hope that makes some sense.

PS this is for a RDBMS based database - not OO.  I tend to use Views to see data from different perspectives.

Thanks.

PS perhaps too the CRON job would mark ScheduledTask as OverDue too rather than determining that.  I guess the question is about whether these formal states should be stored in the database, or determined.  The only way I can store them is to have some kind of CRON job running (which is fine, as long as I know there isn't a better way).

EDIT: One argument against deriving the state is that the Schedule may change - however I do keep history in the database, so I could still derive - but the more I think about it the more I'm leaning towards using a CRON job to schedule tasks based on the schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this model:

[image]

Every time a task is started, insert a new row into WORK table. When it's finished, set WORK.COMPLETED_AT.

You can find daily tasks (and their areas) that have not yet been done today like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM SCHEDULE
WHERE
    FREQUENCY = 'daily'
    AND NOT EXIST (
        SELECT * FROM WORK
        WHERE
            SCHEDULE.AREA_ID = WORK.AREA_ID
            AND SCHEDULE.TASK_ID = WORK.TASK_ID
            AND DAY(COMPLETED_AT) = TODAY
    )
```

Replace DAY and TODAY with whatever is specific to your database, and you'd probably want to use integers instead of strings for FREQUENCY.

Similar queries can be devised for other frequencies.

Manually scheduled tasks could be modeled through a table similar to SCHEDULE, but with FREQUENCY replaced by explicit time(s).